# how to layout tictactoe with html and css on a webpage

Tags: html, css

My question is what html and css features should I research before making tictactoe.

[image]

I'm currently using a HTML table with CSS with ugly X and O characters:

My CSS:

```
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>O</td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td>X</td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td>X</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `td`s a fixed width and height, and [set the `table`'s borders to collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You should also look into [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius).

---

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8YKw/), but the rest is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. This should be all I need apart from how to do the X characters.

Comment: @robertking - Use `&times;` for the X character. See my fiddle.

Comment: what is the benefit of border collapse? Because i checked your fiddle by removing it there is no change

Comment: @Usman - It has no change because it is being automatically set via [**normalize.css**](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), which is automatically included in the fiddle. [Here it is without it](http://jsfiddle.net/z8YKw/1/). See the difference?

Comment: adding some unicode css to make your characters prettier http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/m8qf2/2/

Comment: @albert - well of course. The point of this answer was not to write the code for the OP, just to give him a starting point.

Comment: ok. Thanks for explaining. :). i have this problem in someother website. So it get solved:)